# How to create a dynamic color for radio button on Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can I set the color of radio button changed if the value also changed ?

here is the RadioButton

```
CustomRadioButton(
            horizontal: false,
            elevation: 0,
            absoluteZeroSpacing: false,
            width: 150,
            enableButtonWrap: true,

            //* warna radio button
            selectedColor: warna(),
            unSelectedColor: Color(0XFF343f56),
            // selectedBorderColor: Colors.pink,
            // unSelectedBorderColor: Colors.cyan,
            buttonTextStyle: ButtonTextStyle(selectedColor: Colors.white),
            enableShape: true,
            buttonLables: _buttonLables,
            buttonValues: _buttonValue,
            radioButtonValue: (value) {
              _radio = value;
              print(_radio);
            },
          )
```

and this is the warna function

```
String _radio; //* value radio button
  List<String> _buttonLables = ['Pengeluaran', 'Pemasukan'];
  List<String> _buttonValue = ['PENGELUARAN', 'PEMASUKAN'];

  warna() {
    if (_radio == null) {
      return Colors.blue;
    } else if (_radio == 'PENGELUARAN') {
      return Colors.red;
    } else if (_radio == 'PEMASUKAN') {
      return Colors.green;
    }
  }
```

I'm using a stateful widget but the color only changed when I hot reload the code

Comment: are you calling `setState( () {} )` after changing the color?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm still learning a Flutter

Comment: You will have to call `setState( () {} )` after canging the color... **setState** rebuilds the widget

Comment: Oh I got it, I have to setState on radioButtonValue

Answer (score 1):

I should setState when the value changed

```
radioButtonValue: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _radio = value;
              });
              // _radio = value;
              print(_radio);
            },
```